# Not able to parse multipart/form-data in express.Multer req.file is coming as udefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, body-parser

**I am not able to parse multipart/form-data with express,bodyparser and multer.
Request parameters are undefined. Tried to go through multiple solutions. Still no luck**

> ```
> req.uploadFileName is undefined.
> console.log('Upload file...' + req.file); //undefined
> console.log('Upload file...' + req.files); //undefined
> console.log('Upload uploadFileName...' + req.uploadFileName); //undefined
> console.log('Upload  body' + req.body) //undefined
> ```

**NPM packages**

- "multer": "^1.4.1"
- "express": "^4.16.3"
- "body-parser": "^1.18.3"

  router.post('/', uploadService.getUpload(), uploadService.uploadFile);

  ```
      export const uploadFile = (req, res, next) => {
      console.log('Upload file...' + req.file);
      console.log('Upload file...' + req.files);
      console.log('Upload uploadFileName...' + req.uploadFileName);
      console.log('Upload  body' + req.body);

      let file = req.uploadFileName;
      console.log('Upload fileName' + req.body.uploadFileName);;
      if (file) {
          uploadImageToStorage(file).then((fileURL) => {
              res.json({
                  status: 'success',
                  fileURL: fileURL
              });
          }).catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
              next('failed to upload file ', error)
          });
      } else {
          console.error('failed to upload file ', file);
          next('failed to upload file ', file)
      }
  };

  export const getUpload = () => {
      // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
      const multer = Multer({
          storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
          limits: {
              fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024;
          }

      });
      return multer.single('uploadFileName')
  }
  ```

**Code uploading the file:**
**index.html**

```
<form class="uploadForm" action="/api/v1/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
    <input name="uploadFileName" id="input-1" type="file" class="file">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your Code is working fine. I tested it with postman. How are you uploading file to server? And Are there any errors while uploading?

Comment: updated code, i am using for uploading file.

Comment: Code is working. Your action is not correct please check that and tell me if that's the error.

Comment: Application is split into several files. Action is correct. I can hit the api, only thing is that req.uploadFileName is undefined. If i remove multer middleware i can see the req.body raw request in logs, with multer req.body is undefined too.

apis/index.ts
router.use('/v1', v1API);
v1/index.ts
router.use('/upload', uploadController);

Let me know if you need any other details

Comment: I am getting the same error with this code. Tested in code and with Postman and the req.body always returns empty.